# MS SQL Server: cast double to string and compare text

Tags: sql, sql-server, casting

In MS SQL Server I have a filed of type double that is called `ID`, and that stores ID numbers, surprisingly enough.
Anyway, I want to be able to search ID numberss like text - say I want all ID's that starts with 021 or that ends with 04 - to do so I need to convert the double the string.

My problem is that ID numbers here are 9 digits, so when I try `SELECT str([id])` I get something like `02123+e23`, which is not good for my purpose.

How do I go about converting it to a string that looks exactly the same, and can be compared against other strings?

EDIT: I tried `SELECT str([id],9,0)` and I got the right string, or at least what looked right to me, but when comparing against equal strings the comparison failed. Any ideas why?

Thanks!

Comment: could you add some example input?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If your ID's are stored as numbers, then there will not be prefixed zeros, so finding all records that starts with '021' really means finding those that starts with '21'

```
SELECT * FROM MyTable
WHERE CAST(Id AS VARCHAR) LIKE '21%'
```

Comment: I noticed that this works when I compare numbers that are up to 6 digits exactly. Any more digits and this will fail. Think you know why? Thanks

Comment: Yeah, sorry about that. I forgot that when casting a FLOAT type column to a VARCHAR, it defaults to 6 digits and uses scientific notations when more digits are needed - check this out: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx. To work around this, you could cast your FLOAT data to an INTEGER datatype first, like so: `CAST(CAST(Id AS BIGINT) AS VARCHAR) LIKE '21%'`

Answer (score 1):

`SELECT * FROM tablename
WHERE SUBSTRING(CAST(id AS VARCHAR), 0, 9) =  '123456789'`

Answer (score 0):

You can use the convert method in TSQL, and sepcify the precision : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx (float and real Styles section in the Remarks).

But why can't you convert your string into double to make the comparison ?