# Equivalent of double equals in SQL-Server?

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to write a bit more complex SQL-Server CASE statement:

```
...
and (@StatusID is null or
       (case 
           when @StatusID = 0 and sr.Comment is not null
           else @StatusID == sr.StatusID
       end) 
     = 1)
and ...
```

but I get an error with the double equals sign. I also tried this

```
else @StatusID = sr.StatusID then 1
```

and

```
else @StatusID is sr.StatusID
```

I couldn't find any information on what I am trying to do is possible on SQL-Server.

Comment: Can you please copy the output error message? Also what is the column type of the sr.StatusID?

Comment: Do you want to assign to `@StatusID` or compare with the other value?

Comment: It all depends on the usage. The same `=` symbol is used both for assignments and equals comparisons.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may looking for this

```
and (@StatusID is null or 1 =
   (CASE 
       WHEN @StatusID = 0 AND sr.Comment IS NOT NULL THEN 1
       WHEN @StatusID = sr.StatusID THEN 1
   end) 
 )
```

Comment: `=` missing between `1` and `case`

Answer (score 0):

`CASE WHEN <EXPRESSION> THEN ... ELSE ... END`
Is the syntax you'd want. You've just forgotten the `THEN`. Also, single equals sign is the correct SQL syntax.

Answer (score -1):

[This question and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19153884/ms-sql-server-cast-double-to-string-and-compare-text) might help you.

One way to achieve such comparison is by casting the double to string and comparing them, e.g.:

```
-- select ids (double) that start with '1' by casting them to varchar and using LIKE

SELECT * FROM MyTable WHERE CAST(Id AS VARCHAR) LIKE '1%';
```